# google maps v3 determine which states are within boundaries of circle overlay

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry, geocode

Is there a way to determine which states are within circle overlays created by google.maps.Circle? Perhaps using reverse geocoding and getBounds or contains? Does Google provide a way to do this (using the geocoder or some other method), or must a database of Latitude and Longitude points of states be used?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this within Google Maps API.

You can use `getBounds()` to get a `LatLngBounds` object approximating the circle.  Note though that `getBounds()` will return a rectangle that approximates the circle, so you might get inaccurate results.  To do it more accurately, you'd need to calculate a bunch of points to approximate the circle using something like the Haversine formula in combination with the cirlce's center and radius.  The more points you calculate, the more accurate the approximation.

Once you have your set of bounding points, you're still not exactly out of the woods.  There does not appear to be a way to use Google's Geocoder API to return all the states in a `LatLngBounds`.  So you'd have to calculate a bunch more points within the bounds and send individual reverse geocode requests for them.  And you still might miss a state or two.  Overall, yuck.

Another approach, that doesn't seem that much more appealing to me, but who knows:  For each state, get lat/lng data for a bunch of rectangular bounds that, when all combined together, approximate the shape of the state.  For each state, use `intersects()` to see if it intersects with your circle.

There may be other possibilities, involving Google Maps API or other technologies, depending on your use case.